# Error exporting symbol when cross-compiling ICU for Windows.

Tags: windows, cross-compiling, icu

I am attempting to use Mingw-w64's 32-bit compiler (the `i686-w64-mingw32` toolchain) to cross-compile the ICU library for Windows. The host is Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit.

The steps I have taken look something like this:

1. Grab the latest source code archive from [here](http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/50.1.2/icu4c-50_1_2-src.tgz) and extract it.
2. Make two copies of the `source/` directory - one for the host and one for the target.
3. For the host build:

   ```
   ./configure ; make
   ```
4. For the target build:

   ```
   ./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-cross-build=<host_source_dir>
   ```

   ...where `<host_source_dir>` is the directory from the previous step.
5. When I run `make` in the target source directory, compilation proceeds without any errors for a few moments and then throws this error:

   ```
   i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings
   -Wno-long-long -mthreads  -o ../../bin/uconv.exe uconv.o uwmsg.o
   -L../../lib -licuin50 -L../../lib -licuuc50 -L../../stubdata -licudt50
   -lm   uconvmsg/uconvmsg.a
   uconv.o:uconv.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `_uconvmsg_dat'
   ```

What could be causing this error? I backed up a few lines and also noticed this:

```
pkgdata: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic -Wshadow
  -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -mthreads  -shared
  -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--out-implib=./all.lib  -o
  ../lib/icudt50.dll ./out/tmp/icudt50l_dat.o
Cannot export icudt50_dat: symbol not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
-- return status = 256
Error generating library file. Failed command: i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -Wall
  -std=c99 -pedantic -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-prototypes
  -Wwrite-strings -mthreads -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--enable-auto-import
  -Wl,--out-implib=./all.lib -o ../lib/icudt50.dll ./out/tmp/icudt50l_dat.o   
Error generating assembly code for data.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem was indeed with the ICU source code. I'm not sure I understand exactly what the problem is, but thankfully someone else did and wrote three patches.

The first two apply to my question above:

- [icu4c-50_1_2-crossbuild.patch](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file?file=icu4c-50_1_2-crossbuild.patch&package=mingw64-icu&project=windows%3Amingw%3Awin64)
- [icu4c-4_6_1-win32.patch](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file?expand=1&file=icu4c-4_6_1-win32.patch&package=mingw32-icu&project=windows%3Amingw%3Awin32)

The third patch is used instead of the second in the list above when building for the x86_64 architecture:

- [icu4c-4_6_1-win64.patch](https://build.opensuse.org/package/view_file?file=icu4c-4_6_1-win64.patch&package=mingw64-icu&project=windows%3Amingw%3Awin64&rev=998ad2e0495d85cc55b308eb4cc1bdd8)

There does still seem to be a problem when running `make install`, but at least the source tree seems to build now.

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug your symbol problem just provide the flag `-Wl,--trace-symbol=_uconvmsg_dat` to `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` like follows:

`i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings
-Wno-long-long -mthreads  -o ../../bin/uconv.exe uconv.o uwmsg.o
-L../../lib -licuin50 -L../../lib -licuuc50 -L../../stubdata -licudt50
-lm   uconvmsg/uconvmsg.a -Wl,--trace-symbol=_uconvmsg_dat`